# Specify the Type on a Class Object

Tags: java, generics

The following code calls the setProperty method on a Camel Exchange

`List<Message> list = oldExchange.getProperty("p",List.class);`

The intention is that I retrieve a `List` object that I have previously stored against the `Exchange` instance.

As this code stands, I get a compiler warning ( Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List ).

I know I can make this go away by adding the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation, but is there a way that I can fix it by changing the declaration of `List.class`?

The `getProperty` method has the following signature
`<T> T  getProperty(String name, Class<T> type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here unfortunately your cast cannot be safe, because while you know that returned object has the `List` type, you cannot be sure that all the elements of this list has the `Message` type. So you may get an unexpected `ClassCastException` much later, when you write something like `Message m = list.get(0);`

To make your code robust you have to check all the existing list elements, then you can do the unchecked cast like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> checkElements(List<?> list, Class<T> elementClass) {
    for(Object e : list) {
        elementClass.cast(e); // throw CCE on wrong element
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<T> result = (List<T>)list;
    return result;
}
```

The `@SuppressWarnings` is still necessary inside this method, but it's "library" method, so it's ok here. However in business code you may use now:

```
List<Message> list = checkElements(oldExchange.getProperty("p",List.class), Message.class);
```

The disadvantage of such approach is that it takes some time to check the type of every element. If you 100% sure that you have the correct list, then just use `@SuppressWarnings` in your original code.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done - there is no class literal expression for generic types.

If you have a lot of such calls in your code, you may want to create a utility method to suppress the warnings in one place only:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> T  myGetProperty(String name, Class<?> type) {
    return (T) getProperty(name, type);
}
```

Then this call comes without a warning:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = myGetProperty("a", List.class);
```

However, you need to keep in mind that it is indeed *unchecked* so you can't be sure that the elements of the list are strings.